# How to move rc.conf HARDWARE section to /etc/modules-load.d/?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I've just begun moving my Arch system to systemd, and started by moving the deprecated parts of rc.conf to their respective configuration files.

The [rc.conf wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rc.conf#New_configuration_file) lists files for most options, and I assume I should just move the relevant lines from rc.conf to those files. But what about the HARDWARE sections? A directory is listed there: /etc/modules-load.d/.

Comment: Turns out this is described in the systemd wiki article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Kernel_modules and `man modules-load.d` (can't answer my own question this quickly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules: Use `modules-load.d(5)` for autoloading – if it's still necessary (with Linux 3.5, almost all hardware-specific modules are autoloaded, including `kvm`). Use `modprobe.d(5)` for blacklisting.

FakeRAID: Seems to require `dmraid.service`.

Btrfs: Handled by udev.

LVM: [Will be handled by](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.devel/18541) udev + *lvmetad* starting with lvm2-2.02.98-2; in older packages needs `lvm.service`.